# C singly linked list head points to another node's head

Tags: c, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I know how to point a node's head to have either int value or a char value; however, I am stuck with how to point one node's head to another node's head.

For example,
[nodes head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8WUpP.png)

Node "a"'s next points to another (f) node, whose head points to "b" and whose next points to node "d". I cant figure out how to allow node "f"'s head to point to node "b" and next points to "d". I wrote something like this, but its not working.

```
a->data = 'a';
a->next = f;

f->data = b;
f->next = d;

b->data = 'b';
b->next = c;
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```c
struct node {
  char char_data;
  struct node* node_data;

  struct node* next;
};
```

So you have these nodes:

```c
struct node* a = ...;
struct node* f = ...;
struct node* b = ...;
...

a->char_data = 'a';
a->node_data = NULL;
a->next = f;

f->node_data = b;
f->next = d;

b->char_data = 'b';
b->node_data = NULL;
b->next = c;

...
```

Practically, if `node->node_data` is `NULL`, it means that the node contains a `char`, so you read/set its `node->char_data`; if instead `node->node_data` is *not* `NULL`, it means that the node points to another node, so you ignore its `node->char_data` member, and instead you look at its `node->node_data` member.

Answer (score 0):

consider using tagged union:

```
struct node {
    enum { NODE_CHAR, NODE_INT, NODE_NODE } tag;
    union {
        char c;
        int i;
        struct node *node;
    };
    struct node *next;
};
```

Now you can create a simple tree as:

```
// make a char node
struct node node0 = { .tag = NODE_CHAR, .c = 'a' };
// make it a predeccesor of `int` node
struct node node1 = { .tag = NODE_INT, .i = 42, .next = &node0 };
// make it a simbling of other char node
struct node node2 = { .tag = NODE_CHAR, .c = 'b' };
struct node node3 = { .tag = NODE_NODE, .node = &node2, .next = &node1 };
```